# How do I crawl PDF files so that it is indexed and kept on my server, with Nutch?

Tags: nutch

With Nutch how can I crawl PDFs that are on a website to then index them? Also, is there a way to keep the original PDF on my server after I crawl them, with Nutch?

Answer (score 0):

**If you have the pdf url:** You can directly use it to fetch it. It will store the entire pdf in the db when you fetch it.

**If you dont' have the url**: One solution could be to generate them as outlinks from the website you are crawling. For this, you'll need to write your own parser(or extend the current one) to save pdf URIs as outlinks. So next time when you call updateDb command, they will be saved as new rows in your db and you can fetch them in the next crawl.

Answer (score 0):

The files are in the `segments` folder, just not stored as "normal" pdf files. To reconstruct the files in a segment you can use the command:

```
bin/nutch dump  -outputDir ./out -segment ./crawldir/segments -flatdir
```

#### Notes

1. You can see the complete list of arguments and their descriptions if
   you type `bin/nutch dump` from the command line.
2. The prepended alphanumeric sequence to the files output by the
   above command is the `md5` hash of the site's url.